# Why does it show me the items from previous tabs?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, select

when I click tab-2 it shows me content from tab-1 and tab-2?

How to hide content from tab-1 in tab-2?

I want it to show only a selected genre.

It works well only for tab-1, for other tabs show all previously selected tabs.

I would be very grateful for your help, thank you

This is the PHP code

```
    <div class="container">
            <!-- content tabs -->
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="tab-1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="1-tab">
                    <div class="row row--grid">
                        <!-- card -->

                        <?php
$sql = "
SELECT id
     , gatunek
     , title
     , photo 
  FROM cruda 
 WHERE gatunek = 'Animation'
";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 2) {
  // output data of each row
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>

                        <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-xl-2">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card__cover">
                                <img src="admin-pnel/<?= $row['photo']; ?>" alt="">
                                    <a href="details.html" class="card__play">
                                        <i class="icon ion-ios-play"></i>
                                    </a>
                                    <span class="card__rate card__rate--green">8.4</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card__content">
                                <h3 class="card__title"><a href="details.html"><?= $row['title']; ?></a></h3>
                                    <span class="card__category">
                                    <a href="#"><?= $row['gatunek']; ?></a>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <?php } }?>
                        <!-- end card -->


                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab-2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="2-tab">
                    <div class="row row--grid">


                    <?php
$sql = "SELECT id,gatunek, title, photo FROM cruda WHERE gatunek='Romance'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 2) {
  // output data of each row
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                        <!-- card -->
                        
                        <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-xl-2">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card__cover">
                                <img src="admin-pnel/<?= $row['photo']; ?>" alt="">
                                    <a href="details.html" class="card__play">
                                        <i class="icon ion-ios-play"></i>
                                    </a>
                                    <span class="card__rate card__rate--green">8.4</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card__content">
                                <h3 class="card__title"><a href="details.html"><?= $row['title']; ?></a></h3>
                                    <span class="card__category">
                                    <a href="#"><?= $row['gatunek']; ?></a>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- end card -->
                        <?php } }?>
```

This is the html code tabs

```
    <!-- content tabs nav -->
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs content__tabs" id="content__tabs" role="tablist">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-1" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-1" aria-selected="true">ANIMATION</a>
                            </li>

                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-2" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-2" aria-selected="false">ROMANCE</a>
                            </li>
```

Comment: why did you ask the same question twice?

Comment: i delete earlier

Comment: to meet your expectation use  js to hide or show your tabs as you need

Comment: How to do that, any example ?